# Automatic conversion from file to string after entering in a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7

```
v_file = open('numbers.txt','r')
print (type(v_file))
for v_i in v_file:
   print (v_i.strip('\n'))
   print (type(v_i))
```

Hey there... i'm just wondering how python knows to change automatically from a file type to a string type in this piece of code after entering the for loop.
In "numbers.txt" i have let's say:

```
Peter, 0908212
Joe, 9283812
```

L.T: It just knows and that is it?

Comment: What do you mean *"automatic conversion"*? You're iterating over the file, which contains text, so `v_i` is just each line as a string.

Comment: ok i think i got it, so v_i becomes string because of the text in the file which is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on what you are trying to accomplish, but I'm gonna assume those numbers are in the file. That being said, try:

```
content = v_file.read()
for line in content.split('\n'):
    print line
    ## ... or whatever. Should return those numbers
```

Again, I'm assuming you are just iterating over an open file instance. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: i was just wondering how python know to iterate over that opened file object and how variable v_i becomes a string, but i guess it's just like that. Anyway, could you upvote my question for no reason please? I want to get out of the asking questions ban..if you could do that, it would be greate :)